# Same input for both Reachability and Controllability

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, linear-control

For LTI systems, both Reachability and Controllability are equivalent. Now, this may be a stupid question, but does the same input works for both the cases? I explain myself better : for example, consider two points $x_0=0$ and $x_1=1$. Does the input who drives the system from $x_0$ to $x_1$ also stirs the system from $x_1$ to $x_0$? I think it does, but if it wouldn't, could you give some literature about?

Comment: Have you tried a simple example? Like $\dot{x} = u$ with a constant input. You need to do some work.